# SQL оператор LIKE

Tags: sql

Есть такой запрос с оператором LIKE:

```
SELECT c2p.product_id
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category c2p
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd
ON(c2p.product_id = pd.product_id)
WHERE c2p.category_id = $id AND pd.name LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'"
```

Зависит ли в данном случае оператор LIKE от регистра букв, СУБД MySQL версия 5.5.52?

Если да, как это можно исправить, мне нужно чтобы like не зависел от регистра?

Comment: Во первых вы не указали какой именно SQL имеется ввиду, а от этого многое зависит. вот например первое найденное по MySQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/how-can-i-search-case-insensitive-in-a-column-using-like-wildcard  (т.е. в MySQL можно явно указывать как именно искать, оговаривая это при объявлении колонки или в самом like)

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду что можно сделать так: `UPPER(pd.name) LIKE UPPER('%" . $keyword . "%')`, и like уже не будет зависеть от регистра?

Comment: Ваш keyword экранирован для защиты от SQL-инъекции?

Comment: В следующий раз сразу в вопросе в _тегах_ обозначайте, что у вас MySQL. ответы на большинство вопросов по SQL требуют знания какая СУБД используется

Comment: andreymal, поле keyword я сам заполнял, ничего лишнего там точно нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если хочешь игнорировать регистр букв.тогда используем COLLATE.
и есть варианты.

например
COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI
,COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Employees AS EMP
WHERE   EMP.Name COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%Ekt%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Да,  зависит от регистра букв.

Comment: А вот и не совсем. Просто у сферического SQL в вакууме, конечно зависит. Но в некоторых конкретных реализациях может и не зависеть, например в зависимости от типа колонки или дополнительных ключевых слов добавляемых к самому like. Вы бы уж написали полный ответ, описали бы возможные нюансы.

Answer (score 1):

Да, регистр важен в операторе LIKE

Comment: Я с вами согласен, но, в данном случае я не вижу смысла это делать, я не думаю что автор вопроса на сколько ноль в SQLе, что нужно разжевывать. На его месте меня вполне бы устроил ответ Да, зависит. Логически додумав по имени поля name ясно что там тип строка.

Comment: И что из того, что там видимый тип строка ? Может у него MySQL и колонка _объявлена_ как `VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER 
 SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI` тогда при поиске like по этой колонке регистр будет не важен.